# Xcode 10: The Image set 'customloading' reference a file "mygif.gif" , but that file does not have a valid extension

Tags: ios, xcode

I update my xcode9 to xcode10 then suddenly my gif on my app doesn't view my gif. then when I go the my Assets. that appears.

[image: I update my]

```
class CustomLoading: UIView {

    static let instance = CustomLoading()
    var viewColor: UIColor = .brown
    var setAlpha: CGFloat = 2.0
    var gifName: String = "customloading"

    lazy var transparentView:  UIView = {

        let transparentView = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        transparentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(setAlpha)
        transparentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        return transparentView

    }()
```

Comment: Hi @Guren, welcome to **StackOverflow**, you may take a look to [_"how to ask"_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve this and future questions. Specially you should provide some [_"research effort"_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and/or some code, to prove you already tried to solve the problem by yourself.

Comment: Good day sir. I already did my research regarding with the issue and I can't still find the answer. and my code is running smoothly and when I upgrade my xcode version to 10 I got that warning. and the loading screen is there but the gif won't load.

Comment: @Guren Did you get a solution for same?

Comment: sadly, not sir. @techsavvy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xcode 10 does not support gif on asset so I called it on outside of the asset folder